# Git fetch upstream doesn't see recent updates

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

Workflow I am trying to use:
**upstream/main_branch -> myfork/main_branch.**
     initially via `git clone` then using `git reset --hard upstream/main_branch`
**myfork/main_branch -> myfork/feature_branch.**
     initially via `git checkout -b "feature_branch` then `git rebase main_branch`
**myfork/feature_branch -> upstream/main_branch.**
     via GitHub Pull Request

**My problem is:** I'm sure this process worked in the past ok, but for a while when I now when try to update my myfork/feature_branch from upstream/main_branch (in order to then update myfork/feature_branch) it fails to fetch updates.

```
    git checkout myfork/main_branch
    git fetch upstream
```

exits very quickly and does not have the latest commits I know are in the upstream branch
when I run

```
    git branch -avv
```

The remote branch is listed but still with old commit showing.

Previously running `git fetch upstream refs/heads/main_branch:refs/remotes/upstream/main_branch` has fixed the issue. But I want to know why this is happening and why it gets in to this state?
(I mainly use IntelliJ Idea Git tools)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the exact steps to reproduce your setup? It's not really clear what you did and also why you had to use `git reset --hard` on your branch.

Comment: I do that just to get my local copy of the upstream main_branch without having to rebase...

Comment: Yes, but: If your local branch and the remote are tied, you'd just have to fetch/pull, I think. It still depends a bit on the details, hence my request for a [mcve].

Comment: doesn't a pull bring in merge commits by default? To be fair if I could make a reproducible example I could probably fix it myself...so I think all I can do is provide the current scenario and symptom that are unexpected...I'lll try and make a public toy repo tonight but I expect it will just work in that scenario...

Comment: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*. The second command defaults to `git merge` unless you tell Git to make it default to `git rebase`, but can be specified at the time you run `git pull`. I hardly ever use `git pull` though because to know which second command I want, I have to fetch first and see what I got, and then there's no point in fetching, so I should just run the second command myself once I figure out what it is.

Comment: In any case: check to see whether something has set up `upstream` as a *single-branch* remote, rather than a full-fledged one. Use `git config --get remote.upstream.fetch`. The output is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*` for a full fledged remote, but something else for single-branch ones.

Comment: @torek please add last comment as answer and I will select it. This was the case...

Comment: git config remote.upstream.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*" 

fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR summary

To fix this particular single-branch remote, run:

```
git remote set-branches upstream "*"
```

If that fails to do anything, see the longer section below:

The double quotes here are for Unix-style shells, and should be harmless in `CMD.EXE` I believe (though I don't use Windows).

#### With details

I'm not sure what you did that *created* this state, but based on [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799541/git-fetch-upstream-doesnt-see-recent-updates?noredirect=1#comment118102296_66799541), it appears that `upstream` was created as a *single-branch remote*.<sup>1</sup>  To check for this, run:

```
git config --get-all remote.upstream.fetch
```

(note the `remote.upstream.fetch` here; for a remote named `r` it would be just `remote.r.fetch`; for `origin` it is `remote.origin.fetch`; and so on).  This lists out what a default `git fetch` operation will fetch.  A normal (every-branch) setting would read:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

(again, note that the word `upstream` is embedded in the text: this changes based on the name of the remote).  A single-branch setting for branch `X` would read:

```
+refs/heads/X:refs/remotes/upstream/X
```

(note that `upstream` still appears once, but `X` appears twice).  A "two branch" fetch will read:

```
+refs/heads/X:refs/remotes/upstream/X
+refs/heads/Y:refs/remotes/upstream/Y
```

and so on.  The `git remote` command can be used to alter these settings:

```
git remote set-branches upstream "*"
```

While experimenting a bit, however, I discovered a bug in `git remote set-branches`.  If run as:

```
git remote set-branches upstream
```

it *removes all the fetch settings*, after which `git remote` is unable to *add new ones!*  In this case you might wish to use `git config` directly.

When using `git config` you can write:

```
git config remote.upstream.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*"
```

This will create the `remote.upstream.fetch` setting if it does not exist, or replace a *single* setting if a single setting exists.  However, because the fetch setting is allowed to be multi-valued, you can get an error:

```
$ git config remote.upstream.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*"
warning: remote.upstream.fetch has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change remote.upstream.fetch.
```

In this case, adding `--replace-all` works:

```
git config --replace-all remote.upstream.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*"
```

As another alternative—which is the one I usually use as a first resort anyway—you can run `git config --edit` or `vim .git/config` and just edit the file in place with a sensible editor.  Be sure to use a *sensible* editor though; too many editors insist on turning the file into Rich Text with XML or other markup, or turning the file into a UTF-16 mess, or whatever.

---

<sup>1</sup>In plain command line Git, you'd get this if you ran:

```
git remote add -t <branch> upstream <url>
```

to create the remote named `upstream` using the given *`url`* and *`branch`* as its single branch.

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply. Not sure how I managed to do this but perhaps this is the default then you use use a github clone of a branch since the branch I was on was the one when I first cloned years back..